# Data streaming processing in .net

Tags: .net, apache-flink, apache-pulsar, data-stream

I'm studying some products to implements event sourcing and in general data streaming processing. In particular I have found Apache Pulsar very good for streaming all my events between many microservices, but I would like to process all this data for computing real time output. I have found Apache Flink could be the right product for me, but the problem is written in Java and you're supposed to write in Java your computational code. Do you know if there's something similar in the .NET world, a framework to process real time streaming, keeping state of the computation, more or less as Apache Flink can do? Or do you have any advise on what I can do in alternative to do this using C#?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Apache Flink is unavailable for .NET, since you need to send java libraries with jobs to Flink server. The main streaming option for .NET is Apache Spark
https://github.com/dotnet/spark .
Here is a pulsar connector to Spark
https://github.com/streamnative/pulsar-spark